# Google drive integration?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I want to create a app which fetch the files which stored in my drive account and shows in the publicly in app. In this i was successfully integrated the Drive API to my app but now how i can fetch the files that stored in my google drive account  can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Taken straight from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro):

> You can open files programmatically using the
>   DriveResourceClient.openFile() method or by allowing the user to
>   select a file using a file selector activity created with the
>   DriveClient.newOpenFileActivityIntentSender() method. The file
>   contains a reference to the contents of the file, encapsulated in the
>   DriveContents class, which provides access to read and write the
>   underlying data. You can read the contents of a drive file by
>   accessing an input stream of its contents by calling
>   DriveContents.getInputStream().
>
> To create a file, you can use either the
>   DriveResourceClient.createFile method or the
>   DriveClient.newCreateFileActivityIntentSender() method, which presents
>   a dialog to the user that allows them to create the new file in their
>   Drive.
>
> For more information about how to work with files, see Working with
>   File Contents. For more information about how to create files, see
>   Creating Files

Also, you'll need the [DriveID](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveId.html#getResourceId())

Querying:

```
Query query = new Query.Builder()
                      .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "HelloWorld.txt"))
                      .build();

Task<MetadataBuffer> queryTask = getDriveResourceClient().query(query);
```

Comment: I don't want to create a file i want only to display files publicly which stored in my drive so where i can give my folder id or drive id

Comment: @AjeetJain https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveId

getResourceId() : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveId.html#getResourceId()

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be place all the public files you want in a specific folder, say "public folder".
Now what you have to do is change the permission of that folder into "share folder of type 'Anyone with Link' "
Manually it looks like these:

[image]

Programatically, you would use [permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) and set type to 'anyone'.

Comment: I have do that but now how i can fetches those file and display in my app